# why use asp-controller and asp-action if it is not compulsory

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers

```
@model Task3.Models.NewUser

<form action="" method="post">
    <label>first Name </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter name" name="firstName"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter last name" name="lastName"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This code works even without `asp-controller` and `asp-action`. Why should I use those then?

Comment: You are free to ignore the pattern and shoot yourself in the foot doing it eventually. Just do not expect a lot of sympathy when the bullet flies :) Or from anyone that has to fix your stuff later.

Answer (score 1):

The tag helpers `asp-controller` and `asp-action` **can** be used to automatically generate a target URL but you don’t **have** to use them. All they do is automatically generate the `href` attribute for links and `action` attributes for forms. If you want to fill in thos values manually, there is nothing that’s stopping you from doing that.

However, using the tag helpers has a clear benefit: The actual URL that you have to use depends on various things that affect your application’s routing. So if you use manual values, you have to take that into account. And if your routing changes (for whatever reason), you have to manually update the URLs throughout your templates.

By using the tag helpers, you are attaching the target location to something that is usually rather static: A controller action. So that way, you decouple the template from your routing configuration.

One more note for form actions specifically: If you do not specify a form action, the browser will automatically post to the current URL. So if you have a POST handler on the same route as the form, then you can totally omit the action and depend on that behavior.

Comment: I didn't understand "if your routing changes, you have to manually update the URLs throughout your templates". I feel even if we use asp-controller and asp-action we have to change the values.  @poke

Comment: @MohanKurali Controller and action names are a lot more constant that route definitions. You can change the route template in a single location and invalidate all your hardcoded routes at once while dynamic routes would still work fine.